# flutter plugin, ios build and bundle C++ library using CMake?

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm trying to bind openal soft for ios using a flutter plugin I can't figure out, however how can I make podspec and Xcode know to use the CMakeLists.txt file to build and bundle the openal soft sources into a framework or dylib, as my research sceen to yield, podspec cannot work directly with CMake like gradle can, so how can I make that happen? I saw some saying to open Xcode and add every C/C++ file manually, but that wouldn't work because plugins cannot be opened with Xcode and I am not sure if that will even work because CMake does custom configurations for projects as big as this.

Comment: Plugins can be opened in XCode, otherwise it would be really difficult to write/test the native Swift code.

Comment: yes but it won't exactly help, I am inexperienced in C/C++ but I do believe a lot of configuration needs to be done for openAl soft to be able to properly compile so just throwing a bunch of files there doesn't sound like it would work, also how would that be done? Opening podspec doesn't directly open Xcode